# If stat statement not working

Tags: c++, xcode

i am trying to have an if statement be true or false according to the user input it is given but when i put the conditions in it says this invalid operands to binary expression 
 ('string '(aka 'basic_string') and 'int')

here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
 cout << "   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" << endl;
 cout << "   X                                             X" << endl;
 cout << "   X                    MENU                     X" << endl;
 cout << "   X                                             X" << endl;
 cout << "   X       Press 1 to Play The Word Game.        X" << endl;
 cout << "   X                                             X" << endl;
 cout << "   X       Press 2 Too See a calculator.         X" << endl;
 cout << "   X                                             X" << endl;
 cout << "   X                                             X" << endl;
 cout << "   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" << endl
 << endl;

string userinput;
cin >> userinput;
if (userinput == 1);{

    while (1<2)
    {
        cout << "Enter the Word." << endl;

        string UserInput;
        cin >> UserInput;

        cout << endl << UserInput << " is is not the right word but keep on trying" << endl << endl;

        cout << "Press Enter to Continue.";

        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(255, '\n');
        cin.get();

        return 0;
    }
}
  if (userinput == 2);
  {   int z;
    int x;
    int sum;
    cout << " welcome to the calculator" << endl << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(255, '\n');
    cin.get();

    cout << "enter your first number";
    cin >> z; cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "enter your second number" << endl;
    cin >> x; cout << endl << endl;
    sum = z + x;
    cout << sum;
 }

cin.clear();
cin.ignore(255, '\n');
cin.get();

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  if (userinput == 2);
                    ^^^
```

Likewise, you have semi-colons everywhere after the `if` which I think is not what you wanted.

Comment: that didn't help very much it still says the same thing

Comment: @user1610489 Yes, change it to `int` if you you can't use == if you want to compare string. But your intention is to use integer.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semicolon here:

`if (userinput == 1);{`

`if (userinput == 2);`

And you can't compare a string against an int.

```
string userinput;
cin >> userinput;
if (userinput == 1);{
```

So try

```
int userInput ;
```

If you insist on using a string then look at:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/

Comment: thanks a lot this has been frustrating me for a very long time

Comment: @user1610489 If it helped you can accept the answer, it will also mean people are likely to answer your questions.